# Pass form to another class and extract controls and properties

Tags: c#, winforms

This is more so a general question than an issue I have. I have a form with 30+ controls that I will use to populate a model, which eventually ends up in a database.

I was wondering, however, if I could just pass the whole form object to another class, and pull the contents out in the other class without setting up a whole bunch of getters and setters.

Let's say I have a form Form1, and I make this call:

```
OtherClass.Validate(this)
```

Then, in the OtherClass (which is in a different project in the same solution) I have:

```
public static void Validate(Form1 myForm)
```

I have played around with this a little. In the Validate() method, if I put a watch on `myForm`, I can see all the form controls and properties, but I don't know if there is a way to just pull them out. If I type `myForm.`, intellisense shows me all the standard form methods and properties, but not the controls and properties specific to the form. Has anybody tried this successfully?

Comment: There is no WCF Forms, i guess you mean WPF? Please change your Tags.

Comment: Why not pass the Model instead of the Form, since i guess only the Model needs validation? Generally only pass stuff that needs to be passed. It would be an absolute nightmare to write tests for a method that takes a form as the input and validates the controls.

Comment: The model is the way I was coding it, but I was just curious if you could pass the form.  You're right, the method would pretty much be untestable. I actually hadn't thought that far ahead because I really didn't plan on writing the code like that. Excellent point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may grab controls from a form object using

```
myForm.Controls
```

This gives you a collection of controls within the form. You may iterate through them with a foreach loop.

Example with this [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2mdU.png) containing two buttons. You may use the following code to get the controls text.

```
public static void Validate(Form1 myForm)
{
    foreach (Control control in myForm.Controls)
    {
        string text = control.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Triggering the above function prints the following to the console. [(Using this form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2mdU.png)

> button2
>
> button1

This method works for TextBox and other controls too. However, it may be trickier if you have controls within controls. You may solve that by making a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Each control on a form has a property called "Modifiers":

[image: Modifiers]

It is "Private" by default (for a reason: UI is the most likely subject for changes, any logic outside the form should not depend on controls. One control can be replaced with another, a group of controls can be replaced with a custom control. When controls are public, such change is not incapsulated and triggers changes in many parts of the system)

Controls which are added on a form, are serialized into C# code in form.designer.cs file. Code for textBox1, when it has modifier Private:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Change it to Public like shown on a screenshot, and it will become

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Public controls will be accessible like any other public fields:

```
public static void Validate(Form1 myForm)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myForm.textBox1.text))
    {
        // do smth about empty field
    }
}
```